# how to get imageURL from mysql and display the image in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner.
I want to get the imageURL from mysql and display the image.

This is my code

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "successful";
}

$url= "SELECT imgURL FROM icon WHERE id = 1 ";
$result = mysql_query($url,$conn);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($array));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';*/
?>
```

I can connect mysql.
But there is a problem

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Where is the problem? Dont I  get any information from mysql?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your mixing up the procedural way & the OOP way of mysqli & mysql. May you should take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: You cannot use `mysql_query()` after connecting with `new mysqli(.....)`